# How to find neighbor squares in spatial hashing?

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash, spatial

I implemented spatial hashing in my game algorithm.

My (green point)object can see other objects in current square,
but it is located on the edge of current square and it can't see nearest points in another square.

I want to get objects in neighbor squares (1,2,3)
How to get nearest squares?

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpatialHash<T>
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<T>> dict;
    private Dictionary<T, int> objects;
    private int cellSize;

    public SpatialHash(int cellSize)
    {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        dict = new Dictionary<int, List<T>>();
        objects = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    }

    public void Insert(Vector3 vector, T obj)
    {
        var key = Key(vector);
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key].Add(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            dict[key] = new List<T> { obj };
        }
        objects[obj] = key;
    }

    public void UpdatePosition(Vector3 vector, T obj)
    {
        if (objects.ContainsKey(obj))
        {
            dict[objects[obj]].Remove(obj);
        }
        Insert(vector, obj);
    }

    public List<T> QueryPosition(Vector3 vector)
    {
        var key = Key(vector);
        return dict.ContainsKey(key) ? dict[key] : new List<T>();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(Vector3 vector)
    {
        return dict.ContainsKey(Key(vector));
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        var keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            dict[keys[i]].Clear();
        objects.Clear();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        dict.Clear();
        objects.Clear();
    }

    private const int BIG_ENOUGH_INT = 16 * 1024;
    private const double BIG_ENOUGH_FLOOR = BIG_ENOUGH_INT + 0.0000;

    private static int FastFloor(float f)
    {
        return (int)(f + BIG_ENOUGH_FLOOR) - BIG_ENOUGH_INT;
    }

    private int Key(Vector3 v)
    {
        return ((FastFloor(v.x / cellSize) * 73856093) ^
                (FastFloor(v.y / cellSize) * 19349663) ^
                (FastFloor(v.z / cellSize) * 83492791));
    }
}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: mm.. and where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as a new method to the class:

```
//get the list of objects that are in the cell that is specified cells away 
//in each direction from the given location 
public List<T> QueryRelativePosition(Vector3 vector, 
                             int cellsLeft, int cellsUp, int cellsForward)
{
    float posLeft = ((float) cellsLeft)/cellSize;
    float posUp = ((float) cellsUp)/cellSize;
    float posForward = ((float) cellsForward)/cellSize; 
    return QueryPosition(vector + (posLeft * Vector3.left) + 
                                  (posUp * Vector3.up) +
                                  (posForward * Vector3.forward) );
}
```

I would change QueryPosition into a private method and have only this one as public to keep the api small and manageable - but you can keep them both public.

I'm not sure what plane your image is on, but as you are using all 3 components this method allows you to move in all 3 axis by cells (so now you can inspect the adjacent ones easily - but you can use it to inspect far cells as well).

Comment: thanks for reply. i found  better solution for my problem here http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html#design-decisions ,  nevertheless finaly i decided to use quadtree. it's more suitable for objects with different sizes and operating with them.